# Defining a identfier and using it in a struct

Tags: c

Is it possible to define a and identifier and then use it in a struct?

e.g.

```
#define APPLE   1

typedef struct
{
 UINT32 banana;
 APPLE; 
}Fruits
```

I want to make sure I'm not violating some rule.

Thank you

Comment: Does `APPLE;` make sense by itself?

Comment: As it is currently `#define`d this won't compile. Can you provide a more representative (example) definition of `APPLE`?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of #define as a copy/paste preprocessor command. So, in general if I understood the question, the answer is yes. But in your example it ends up something like:

```
typedef struct
{
 UINT32 banana;
 1; 
}Fruits
```

Answer (score 0):

A `#define` tells the preprocessor to replace one piece of text with another.  Wherever you write `APPLE`, the copmpiler will think you wrote `1`.

So, your example is equivalent to:

```
typedef struct
{
 UINT32 banana;
 1; 
}Fruits
```

…which is not valid syntax since `1;` isn't a valid field declaration in the structure.  (And you're missing a semicolon at the end.)